# Rails 4: Missing Template in CSV downloading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

There is a `CSV` download feature in the `misc_definitions controller`. The downloading `CSV` is implemented with `form_tag` in `index.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_tag misc_definitions_path(format: "csv", definition_category: 'role_definition'), method: :get do %>
           <div class="form-inputs">
              <%= label_tag(:index_from, "Index From") %>
              <%= text_field_tag('index_from', '1', size: 6) %>
              <%= label_tag(:token, "Token ") %>
              <%= text_field_tag('token?', '', size: 12) %>

             <%= submit_tag 'CSV' %>
           </div>
      <% end %>
```

In `index` controller, it is:

```
  def index 
   .....
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {@misc_definitions = @misc_definitions.page(params[:page]).per_page(@max_pagination) }
        format.csv do
          send_data @misc_definitions.role_to_csv('role_definition', params[:index_from].to_i, params[:token?]) if @definition_category == 'role_definition'
        end
      end
    end
```

After clicking `CSV` on `index` page, the code in `action index` above should be executed and start to download after hitting `format.csv`. However there is error of template missing:

```
Missing template project_misc_definitionx/misc_definitions/index, project_misc_definitionx/application/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:"zh-CN"], :formats=>[:csv], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "C:/D/code/rails_proj/cis/app/views" * "C:/D/code/rails_proj/engines/user_manualx/app/views" * "C:/D/code/rails_proj/engines/project_misc_definitionx/app/views" *
```

I am wondering why `submit CSV` do not hit the `action index` instead even though there is `index.html.erb` under `C:/D/code/rails_proj/engines/user_manualx/app/views`. What am I missing here in the `CSV` downloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the `if` statement at the end of this line the culprit?

```
send_data @misc_definitions.role_to_csv('role_definition', params[:index_from].to_i, params[:token?]) if @definition_category == 'role_definition'
```

It's not going to run `send_data` with the CSV data unless `@definition_category`'s value is `role_definition`. In other cases, Rails will look for a view template to run.

Comment: You are right!. It is a little strange that the params is missing. But it is the problem. Thanks.